# How to properly pause the main thread with a loading screen without freezing UI until condition is met,

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Hello stackoverflow and thank you in advance.

I'm trying to load up a loading menu, until thread has filled an array to at least the size of 5, but the UI freezes.

I have a "new game" Button, when the user clicks it, a thread is created, this thread is responsible for filling an Array, this thread is working fine in the background.

Meanwhile in the main thread, I'm trying to show a loading menu with a nice animation of "loading" as soon as the user clicks the "new game" Button.
I want this menu to be shown until (Array.size < 5) and only then procced to

```
gameLayout.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
```

I know this is the most horrible solution, but I had to do it to prevent crashes until I figure out how to do it properly. The loading screen begins being "visible" and immediately stops before it is visible because UI freezes.

```
loadingLayout.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE)
while(Array.size < 5)
{

}
loadingLayout.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE)
gameLayout.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE)
```

What could be the best way to do it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads

Answer (score 2):

> How to properly pause the main thread.

**You don't**. The main thread (also referred to as the UI thread) should never be blocked.

You say you have your background work in place. The condition should calculated on the background thread as part of the work, and once met any results passed back to the UI thread.